# How to use refundCreate graphQL on Shopify?

Tags: graphql, shopify

I want to make a refund manually tho, I got an error. The below image is GraphiQL at that time.

[Mutation]

```
mutation refundCreate($input: RefundInput!) {
  refundCreate(input: $input) {
    order {
      id
    }
    refund {
      id
    }
    userErrors {
      field
      message
    }
  }
}
```

```
{
  "input": {
    "orderId": "gid://shopify/Order/2546480939164",
    "transactions": {
      "amount": 7,
      "gateway": "manual",
      "kind": "REFUND",
      "orderId": "gid://shopify/Order/2546480939164",
      "parentId": "gid://shopify/Order/2546480939164"
    }
  }
}
```

[The error]

```
{
{
  "data": {
    "refundCreate": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "invalid id",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "refundCreate"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "extensions": {
    "cost": {
      "requestedQueryCost": 20,
      "actualQueryCost": 0,
      "throttleStatus": {
        "maximumAvailable": 1000,
        "currentlyAvailable": 1000,
        "restoreRate": 50
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The below is Order information that I want to refund.

```
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "gid://shopify/Order/2546480939164",
            "customer": {
              "id": "gid://shopify/Customer/3750294814876",
              "firstName": "Hiroshi",
              "lastName": "Ueda",
              "phone": null
            },
            "name": "#1002",
            "refunds": [],
            "lineItems": {
              "edges": [
                {
                  "node": {
                    "id": "gid://shopify/LineItem/5637576818844",
                    "sku": "CK0102",
                    "name": "Chicken LEG Meat Skin-on",
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "refundableQuantity": 1,
                    "requiresShipping": false,
                    "image": {
                      "id": "gid://shopify/ImageSource/9771770806428",
                      "originalSrc": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0417/0262/1340/products/ChickenLegMeat_Skin-on.jpg?v=1593188882"
                    },
                    "product": null
                  }
                },
                {
                  "node": {
                    "id": "gid://shopify/LineItem/5637576851612",
                    "sku": "CK0101",
                    "name": "Chicken LEG Meat Skinless",
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "refundableQuantity": 1,
                    "requiresShipping": false,
                    "image": {
                      "id": "gid://shopify/ImageSource/9771771265180",
                      "originalSrc": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0417/0262/1340/products/ChickenLegMeat_Skinless.jpg?v=1593188883"
                    },
                    "product": null
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
```

When I deleted the parent_id, I got another error like this.

"Transactions not on 'store-credit', 'exchange-credit', or 'cash' gateways require a parent_id".

Do you guys any samples to refund?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it.

I set `"gateway": "exchange-credit",` instead of parent_id.

Thanks